# List Gradle tasks before dependency evaluation

Tags: gradle

Is there a way to list the explicitly called tasks in Gradle?  For example, if task1 dependsOn task2 and task2 dependsOn task3, and I call gradle to execute task1 and task3, I'd like a function that returns `['task1', 'task3']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`StartParameter`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html) object in the `settings.gradle` file:

```
println startParameter.taskNames
```